# Call Parent Component function through Nested Component

Tags: javascript, angular, components

I have an issue with my Angular code. I want to call a function of the Parent component, from the Nested component which is created by the `Component()` Angular function.

Please see my code below:

```
import {
    Compiler, Component, ComponentRef, Injector, NgModule, NgModuleRef, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef
} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { FormsModule, NgForm } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpService } from './ht.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-module-routing',
  templateUrl: './module-routing.component.html'
})
export class ModuleRoutingComponent {

  @ViewChild('vc', {read: ViewContainerRef}) vc: ViewContainerRef;
  private cmpRef: ComponentRef<any>;

  private module_name: string;
  private module_link: any;

  private module_links = [
        {"access": "salessalquoent", "link": "sales\/sales_order_entry.php?NewQuotation=Yes"},
    ];

  constructor(private compiler: Compiler,
                private injector: Injector,
                private m: NgModuleRef<any>,
                private route: ActivatedRoute,
                private httpService: HttpService) {}

  test() { //<-- Want to Call this function
      alert('function called successfully');
  }

  printPage(template, httpService, link) {

      const styles = [`input { width: 100px, display: block }`];
      const tmpCmp = Component({ template, styles }) (
          class {
              OnSubmit(form: NgForm) {
                  console.log(form);

                  this.ModuleRoutingComponent.test(); //<-- Want to call Parent Component function here

                  httpService.getPage(link, form.value)
                      .subscribe(
                          data => this.instance.printPage(data, httpService, link)
                      );
                  return false;
              };
          }
      );

      const tmpModule = NgModule({
          imports: [FormsModule],
          declarations: [tmpCmp]
      })(class {});

      this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
          .then((factories) => {
              const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
              this.cmpRef = f.create(this.injector, [], null, this.m);
              this.cmpRef.instance.name = 'someForm';
              this.vc.insert(this.cmpRef.hostView);
          });
  }
}
```

Please see my comments within code, you will see what I actually mean:

```
//<-- Want to Call this function
```

and

```
//<-- Want to call Parent Component function here
```

Comment: I have tried to handle onsubmit within parent component but its not worked. May be that is better solution if there any way to make it work within parent component where html parsed witin child component.